# Why are none of the folders in my Clojure classpath considered directories and why do none of the files exist?

Tags: windows, clojure, java-io

Below is the code I'm running from a REPL (in [Light Table](http://www.lighttable.com/)) about which I'm currently confused.

This seems to work fine:

```
(require '[clojure.java.classpath :as classpath])

(import '[java.io File])

(map #(File. (.toURI %))
  (classpath/classpath))
```

Results:

```
(#<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\test>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\src>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\dev-resources>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\resources>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\target\classes>
...
```

But then the following seems to indicate that none of the files are directories:

```
(filter #(.isDirectory (File. (.toURI %)))
  (classpath/classpath))
```

Results:

```
()
```

**EDIT** – I'm pretty sure the following is a simpler version of the code about which I'm confused; it produces the same results:

```
(filter #(.isDirectory %)
  (classpath/classpath))
```

However, this seems to work:

```
(filter #(.isDirectory (File. (URLDecoder/decode (.getPath %))))
  (classpath/classpath))
```

Results:

```
(#<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\test>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\src>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\resources>
 #<File C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Kenny\My%20Documents\hello-heroku-clojure-world\target\classes>)
```

[All of the other files in my classpath are JAR files.]

**EDIT** – I'm running this on Windows XP.

**EDIT** – surely this is an issue with paths and spaces; I ran the following:

```
(filter #(.exists %)
  (classpath/classpath))
```

Results:

```
()
```

The relevant code from [`clojure.java.classpath`](https://github.com/clojure/java.classpath/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/classpath.clj):

```
(defn loader-classpath
  "Returns a sequence of File paths from a classloader."
  [loader]
  (when (instance? java.net.URLClassLoader loader)
    (map io/as-file (.getURLs ^java.net.URLClassLoader loader))))
```

Comment: `(filter #(.isDirectory %) (clojure.java.classpath/classpath))` worked for me.

Comment: That's strange. You don't have the spaces encoded as `%20` when you just do `(clojure.java.classpath/classpath)`. Do you?

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin – yeah, I do; I'm guessing it's a 'bug' in `classpath`.

Comment: @Jared314 – I expect the code to work, hence the confusion. I suspect that `classpath` doesn't work well with Windows for directories with spaces in the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the spaces in your paths. This was fixed in version `0.2.1`, but the readme was not updated, and still says `0.2.0`.

Use `[org.clojure/java.classpath "0.2.1"]` in your project.clj `:dependencies` vector.

**Note:** The [`clojure.java.classpath/classpath-directories`](https://github.com/clojure/java.classpath/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/classpath.clj#L66) function will filter the directories for you.